# File association to execute an application from specific directory with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

am trying to make an association for my application, but since my application has some relative path to work correctly am having a problem with normal configuration.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.de\OpenWithProgids"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "DesignerFile.de"; ValueData: ""; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\DesignerFile.de"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Designer"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\DesignerFile.de\DefaultIcon";          \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\DesignerFile.de\shell\open\command"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: "cd ""{app}\"" && ""{#MyAppExeName}"" --file ""%1"""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\{#MyAppExeName}\SupportedTypes"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: ".de"; ValueData: ""
```

So what I've done is to add a second command into value data in order to change the current working directory into that one and then open it.

But it still not working.
I can see the icon in the `.de` files of my application but can't open them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fix your application. That's the best solution.

---

In case you cannot: I'd expect that the `command` must be an actual executable. The `cd` is not an executable, it's an internal command of `cmd` shell.

This might work:

```
cmd.exe /c cd "path" && "program"
```